# Lotus notes - how to view forms as HTML?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have just installed lotus designer 9, and I created a new project with a notebook template. Now I am looking through forms, views, pages etc. and I can see all the controls, at the bottom I have so-called 'programmers pane', but if I wanted to put some of my own html, or adjust a little bit the existing one, I cannot.

So my question is - how do I enable html view? When I open a form, and go to `View`, I can see that there is an option `HTML Editor`, but it is grayed out, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML is not the storage format for forms, behind the scenes. Forms are stored in a proprietary rich text format, and conversion between that and HTML is not exact. So there is no "HTML view" of a Notes form.

You can type HTML text onto the form, highlight it, and designate it as "pass-thru" (Menu 'Text > Pass-Thru HTML'). If accessed via the web, the exact HTML you enter here will be included in the HTML sent to the browser. The Notes client will also convert pass-thru HTML to Notes rich text for display, provided this option has been enabled in the form properties.

Comment: There is also the Preview In Browser feature in the menus. (I don't have ND9 installed, so I can't say exactly where.)